# How can I limit a pandas time series to the n last seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, series

I've a pandas time series

```
time_series = pd.Series(data=[3,4,5], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-07-07 00:06:00.283', '2020-07-07 00:06:02.542', '2020-07-07 00:06:02.829']), name='I'))
```

with ISO formatted `datetime` timestamps as [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). How can I get a subset of the time series which corresponds to the last n seconds (e.g. 1 second)?

Comment: What is your expected output from this Series?

Comment: W.r.t. the example above and a time delta of 1 second I'd expect the data which correspond to `'2020-07-07 00:06:02.542', '2020-07-07 00:06:02.829'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single liner using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) would be

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

time_series = pd.Series(data=[3,4,5], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-07-07 00:06:00.283', '2020-07-07 00:06:02.542', '2020-07-07 00:06:02.829']), name='I')

time_series.loc[time_series.index >= max(time_series.index) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)]
# 2020-07-07 00:06:02.542    4
# 2020-07-07 00:06:02.829    5
# Name: I, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the last value of your index and substract a custom time step from it and then select all indices with larger values

```
n_sec = 1
time_series.index = pd.to_datetime(time_series.index, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
first_value = time_series.index.max() - pd.to_timedelta(n_sec, unit='s')
```

which should produce

```
> print(time_series[first_value:])
2020-07-07 00:06:02.542    4
2020-07-07 00:06:02.829    5
Name: I, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hm, I get `TypeError: Cannot convert input [DatetimeIndex(['2020-07-07 00:12:40.200000+00:00',
                  '2020-07-07 00:12:39.200000+00:00',
                  '2020-07-07 00:12:37.200000+00:00'],
                  dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)] of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> to Timestamp`

Comment: Your code worked. However I like the single line solution of @Ric_S better.